# What does it mean to assign a parent object equal to a child object in Java

Tags: java, inheritance

I'm going over a question and answer key from a practice midterm, but I can't seem to come up with why the answers are what they are.  I get different answers...Can you help me break down what is going on?  There are 3 classes, 1 with just a main method. The main method is where I am having trouble following.  The correct output is:  5, 8, 12.  I keep getting 5, 8, 10...

```
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Add A = new Add(3);
        DAdd DA = new DAdd(1, 5);
        A.addIt(2);
        System.out.println(A.getIt());
        A = DA;         // <-------- Here, what does this mean?
        A.addIt(2);
        System.out.println(A.getIt());
        DA.doubleIt(2);    // <----- only changes DA, not A
        System.out.println(A.getIt())    // <-------- Here, A is the same, right?
    }
```

1. What does it mean when `A = DA;`  // It's setting a parent object to a child object.  Now, I know that `A` doesn't get all the values of `DA`, but what does it get, or what changes from this operation?
2. On the last line, `System.out.println(A.getIt())`, wouldn't that be the exact same value as the previous `system.out.println` value?  We're only getting `A`, not `DA`.  `DA` was the only thing changed in the line before it, so `A` should be there same, right?

Here's the code:

```
public class Add {
    int i;

    Add(int a) {
        i = a;
    }

    void addIt(int amount) {
        i +=amount;
    }

    int getIt() {
        return i;
    }
}


public class Dadd extends Add {
    int i;
    Dadd(int a, int b) {
        super(a);
        i = b;
    }

    void addIt(int amount) {
        i = i*super.i + amount;
    }

    void doubleIt(int amount) {
        addIt(2*amount);
    }

    int getIt() {
        return i +1;
    }
}


public class TestAdder {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Add A = new Add(3);
        Dadd DA = new Dadd(1,5);
        A.addIt(2);
        System.out.println(A.getIt());
        A = DA;
        A.addIt(2);
        System.out.println(A.getIt());
        DA.doubleIt(2);
        System.out.println(A.getIt());
    }

}
```

Comment: `A` and `DA` are not objects - they are variables, which hold references, to objects.

Comment: oh right!!! Thank you!

Comment: `A = DA` : You set the reference that the variable A is holding to be the same as the one DA is holding. Now you have two variables pointing to the same object (of type `Dadd`). You can do that because class `Dadd` "is a" `Add`. The only difference is the type of declaration, so you will only be able to use the methods made public by the `Add` class in the `Dadd` object through `A`.

Comment: @EricNguyen References of  `Add` can hold objects of `Add` 's child classes. Therefore `A = DA`.  Here `A` is just a reference and the properties of the object `A` hold don't change according to the type of reference